# Alternative definition of subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, definition

[image]

In this definition, do the subsequences always have an infinite number of terms? I'm a bit confused about the notations used here. Are $\{n_k\}$ the sequence of ALL positive integers, i.e. $\{n_k\} = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,...\}$, and what the definition says is that we pick an infinite subset of $\{n_k\}$, and use them as indices in $\{{p_n}_i\}$?

Comment: I'm stressing the "infinite" part because I'm trying to prove the statement following the definition, and the definition of convergent sequences seems to apply only to sets of infinite number of terms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they always have an infinite number of terms, that is implied by the dots in $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \cdots $

$\{n_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ can be any infinite sequence of natural numbers. For example it might be the case that you want $n_k = 2k$, or $n_k = k^2$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

So, if you're original sequence equals
$$ (1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,\dots) $$
then the subsequence in the first example equals
$$ (4,16,36,64,\dots) $$
and in the second example equals
$$ (1,16,81,256,\dots) $$

I hope this helps. If you have any questions feel free to comment!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm sorry for the typo.

Comment: I edited my answer a little bit with respect to the typo.